# How do I get package-info using 'apt-cache show' for a specific version of a package in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management

For example, running
`apt-cache show bash` shows info of the bash package for `version: 5.0-6ubuntu1.1` as it is latest.

How to specify the command for an older version, let's say bash package with `version: 4.3-6ubuntu1`?
If not possible with `apt-cache show`, are there any other commands for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-cache` only shows current server information (updated via `apt update` or `apt-get update`) of existing packages in the repository.  What a package is updated, it replaces older versions of the package unless that version is required by another suite.

When I [search Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=bash) for `bash`, I see these versions:

```
    xenial (16.04LTS) 4.3-14ubuntu1.4
    xenial-updates    4.3-14ubuntu1.4
    bionic (18.04LTS) 4.4.18-2ubuntu1
    bionic-updates    4.4.18-2ubuntu1.2
    focal (20.04LTS)  5.0-6ubuntu1
    focal-updates     5.0-6ubuntu1.1
    groovy (20.10)    5.0-6ubuntu2
    hirsute           5.1-2ubuntu1
```

If you want to `apt-cache` to show you information about several versions of `bash`, you'll need to add the relevant suites to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then `apt update`. This will give `apt-cache` information about the versions available in other suites.  Then use `apt show -a bash` to see the information about all packages.

In debian testing, `man apt-cache` says that `-a` is the default behaviour, but this might be a mistake because I find that I need to explicitly specify `-a`, or I'll only see the most recent (or locally installed) version and a little message that says something like "there are more versions available, use -a to see them"

Answer (score 1):

Using `apt changelog bash` command, it will display the changes in the packaged versions, this includes modifications made during of the package developpement.